# I can't connect to sql anywhere 16 database

Tags: java, database, eclipse, database-connection, sqlanywhere

I have been try to connect with a sql anywhere (v. 16) but what i get is

```
(java.sql.SQLException: [Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Database server not found) error.
```

This is my code:

```
public class DBConnection {

private LoginGUI loginGUI;
protected Connection conn;  

String dbName = "CPO";

public DBConnection(LoginGUI loginGUI) {
    this.loginGUI=loginGUI;

    String user = loginGUI.getUsernameStr();
    String passwd = loginGUI.getPasswordStr();

    String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=" + user + ";pwd=" + passwd + ";eng=demo"; 

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl);
        loginGUI.getLoginFrame().setVisible(false);
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't connect to database");
        System.err.println("(" + e + ")\n");

    }       
}


public Connection connection() {

    return this.conn;
}


}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `dbName = "CPO"`? It looks like the value to be used for `eng` instead of `demo`. Oh and please to a `e.printStackTrace()` instead of just outputting the message. Often enough there is a "Caused by"-block that provides additional information about the nature of the error.

Comment: CPO is the name of the database i want to access

Comment: Then pass it to the connection-string instead of `demo`

Comment: The error remains the same. I've changed the output message to e.printStackTrace() and the error is in conn = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl);

Comment: We're talking about SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere 16.0 that runs on the same system as your Java code, corrent?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JDBC driver for SQL Anywhere 16, you need to change it to the following:

```
jdbc:sybase:Tds:[server-ip]:[port]/[dbName]
```

See [SAP's documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/dbname-jconnect-jdbc.html) about this.

Alternatively you might check out the open source JDBC driver [jtds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/?source=navbar) that supports SQL Anywhere as well. In that case the connection string would be

```
jdbc:jtds:sybase://[server-ip]:[port]/[dbName]
```